# Execute immediate 'alter trigger ... disable' with pragma autonomous_transaction in a trigger crashes Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

I'm trying to denormalize these two tables with a Pre-Join denormalization and have to add all the needed triggers.

The tables look basically like this:

```sql
CLIENTS 
Client_ID CHAR(13),
Client_Name VARCHAR2(20),
Client_Surname VARCHAR2 (30),
...
PRIMARY KEY (Client_ID)


ACCOUNTS
Account_ID VARCHAR(20),
...
Client_ID CHAR(13),
Client_Name VARCHAR2(20),
Client_Surname VARCHAR2(30),
PRIMARY KEY (ACCOUNT_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Client_ID) REFERENCES CLIENTS(Client_ID)
```

I have two triggers that are relevant to my question; One is used to disable manual editing of Client_Name and Client_Surname and looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACCOUNTS_NAME_SURNAME_UPDATE_DISABLE 
BEFORE UPDATE OF CLIENT_NAME, CLIENT_SURNAME ON ACCOUNTS 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( NUM => -20002, MSG => 'Updating client_name and client_surname is not permitted!');
END;
```

And the second trigger is used to automatically insert client name and surname when a new account is added, that is connected to a client. It looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACCOUNTS_INSERT_UPDATE 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ACCOUNTS 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    new_name VARCHAR2(20);
    new_surname VARCHAR2(30); 
BEGIN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER ACCOUNTS_NAME_SURNAME_UPDATE_DISABLE DISABLE';

    INSERT Client_Name INTO new_name FROM CLIENTS 
    WHERE Client_ID = :NEW.Client_ID; 

    :NEW.Client_Name := new_name;

    INSERT Client_Surname INTO new_surname FROM CLIENTS 
    WHERE Client_ID = :NEW.Client_ID; 

    :NEW.Client_Surname := new_surname;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER ACCOUNTS_NAME_SURNAME_UPDATE_DISABLE ENABLE';
END;
```

And it works! As long as I remove Execute immediate statements and pragma autonomous transaction (and disable the first trigger manually). It achieves the desired effect - it populates the row with Client's name and surname.

But the moment I add pragma autonomous transaction and execute immediate statements, the Apex Oracle (SQL Commands) page freezes and then it crashes and I have to reload the page.

It is a requirement to use triggers to achieve this effect, although it does seem rather unfitting for the job.

I'm using the newest version of Oracle Apex, which is Oracle APEX 22.1.0-17 at the time of writing this question.

I'd appreciate anyone's help in fixing this mess. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In addition to Littlefoot's excellent comment - there is no reason to use the pragma autonomous transaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both row-level triggers fire `BEFORE UPDATE` on `accounts` table. As if Oracle can't decide it and tries to disable a trigger which is just firing to inform you that you're trying to do something you aren't supposed to and - kind of - ends up in an infinite loop.

So, which trigger will run first? As far as I can tell, Oracle doesn't specify it, but lets **you** decide it using `follows` and `precedes`. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER accounts_name_surname_update_disable
   BEFORE UPDATE OF client_name, client_surname
   ON accounts
   FOR EACH ROW
   FOLLOWS accounts_insert_update                   --> this
BEGIN
   raise_application_error (
      num  => -20002,
      msg  => 'Updating client_name and client_surname is not permitted!');
END;
```

This trigger can be simplified (BTW, code you posted seems to be invalid; there's no such an `INSERT` statement - should've been `SELECT`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER accounts_insert_update
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON accounts
   FOR EACH ROW
   PRECEDES accounts_name_surname_update_disable    --> this
DECLARE
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER ACCOUNTS_NAME_SURNAME_UPDATE_DISABLE DISABLE';

   SELECT client_name, client_surname
     INTO :new.client_name, :new.client_surname
     FROM clients
    WHERE client_id = :new.client_id;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER ACCOUNTS_NAME_SURNAME_UPDATE_DISABLE ENABLE';
END;
```

---

On the other hand - even if that works - the whole process looks wrong to me. How will `accounts_name_surname_update_disable` trigger know that it should - or should not - fire and allow changes to those two columns? To me, only one trigger would suffice - the second one (but modified).

So: drop trigger `accounts_name_surname_update_disable` as it is useless.

Recreate the 2nd trigger: no need to disable/enable anything as that *another* trigger doesn't exist any more. Always fetch client name from `clients` (so, it doesn't matter that someone might *type* those values - trigger will override them):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER accounts_insert_update
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON accounts
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT client_name, client_surname
     INTO :new.client_name, :new.client_surname
     FROM clients
    WHERE client_id = :new.client_id;
END;
```

---

**Finally**, is that all? I don't think so. The whole data model is wrong.  `ACCOUNTS` table should contain **only** `CLIENT_ID` column which is a foreign key, looking at `CLIENTS.CLIENT_ID`:

```
create table clients 
  (client_id        number primary key,
   client_name      varchar2(20) not null,
   client_surname   varchar2(20) not null
  );
  
create table accounts
  (account_id       number primary key,
   client_id        number constraint fk_acc_cli references clients (client_id)
  );
```

Therefore, when `accounts` needs to know client's name, query will perform a **join** and fetch that data:

```
select a.account_id, c.client_name
from accounts a join clients c on c.client_id = a.client_id
where a.account_id = 1234;
```

And that should solve your problem.